# информация обновляется не с первого а со второго раза при нажатии Enter

Tags: reactjs, redux

изначально в хранилище существует пустой массив, когда я ввожу данные для поиска в полученных по get запросу данных срабатывает со 2-го раза, а при первом нажатии в консоле выводит undefined

**SearchForm**

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './SearchForm.css'
import {FaSearch} from 'react-icons/fa';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { ArrayOfItemsFound } from '../store/slices/SearcherSlice'

const SearchForm = () => {
  
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [bookData, setData] = useState([]);

  const searchBook=(evt)=>{
    if(evt.key==="Enter")
    {
      axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q='+ search +'&key=AIzaSyAUrWbMHIWA-7gKEhRCU1FzkyAawM7TBJA')
      .then(response => {
        setData(response.data)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Ошибка при запросе к API:', error);
      });

      const searchResult = bookData
      dispatch(ArrayOfItemsFound(searchResult))

    }
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div className='search-form'>
        <div className='container'>
          <div className='search-form-content'>
            <div className='search-form'>
              <div className='search-form-elem flex flex-sb bg-white'>
                <input type="text" className='form-control' placeholder='Name of book...'
                  value={search} 
                  onChange={e=>setSearch(e.target.value)}
                  onKeyUp={searchBook}/>
                <button className='flex flex-c'>
                  <FaSearch className='text-light-black' size={28} />
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </>
  )
}

export default SearchForm
```

**BookList.js**

```
const BookList = () => {
  const {totalItems, items} = useSelector(state => state.searcher.value)


        return (
          <div className='BookList'>
            <div className="container">
              <div className="BookList-content flex flex-column">
                <div className="BookList-amountOfResults text-black">
                  Found {totalItems} results
                </div>
                <div className="BookList-books">
                  {console.log(items)}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        )
}

export default BookList
```

**SearcherSlice**

```
    import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const searcherSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'searcher',
  initialState: {
    value: {
      totalItems: '0',
      items: []
    }
  },
  reducers: {
    ArrayOfItemsFound: (state, action) => {
      state.value = action.payload
    }
  }
})

export const { ArrayOfItemsFound } = searcherSlice.actions

export default searcherSlice.reducer
```

**Вывод в консоль**

```
[] // при загрузке страницы
BookList.jsx:17 undefined // после 1 нажатия enter
BookList.jsx:17 (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] // после 2 нажатия enter
```

Comment: Когда ты выполняешь `const searchResult = bookData` данные в `bookData` еще не записаны... Как вариант - делать это нужно "рядом" с `setData(response.data)`

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: вы имеете ввиду сразу напрямую после этой строчки сделать так?  
setData(response.data)
dispatch(ArrayOfItemsFound(bookData))

Comment: ничего не поменялось(

Comment: Так не поменяется... Поскольку Изменение стейта асинхронное действие. Вот так пробуй `dispatch(ArrayOfItemsFound(response.data))`

Comment: я пробовал такую же строчку только передавал именно bookData, ничего не работало, а ваша строчка сразу заработала, спасибо!

Comment: Дело в том что сама `bookData` поменяется "потом". Стейт меняется асинхронно, не сразу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В функции `searchBook` вы отправляете асинхронный запрос на сервер, т.к. он асинхронный, то код выполняется дальше и выполняет строчки

```
const searchResult = bookData
dispatch(ArrayOfItemsFound(searchResult))
```

Когда у вас выполняются эти строчки, данные с сервера еще не пришли и не выполнилась строчка `setData(response.data)`. `bookData` к этому моменту у вас равна `[]` по этому `searchReult=[]` соответственно в редьюсер вы передаете массив и `searcher.value` становиться равным `[]`. В `BookList` вы пытаетесь взять свойство `items` у `searcher.value`, а т.к. оно равно `[]`, то очевидно свойства `items` у него нет, по этому и получаете `undefined`.

Когда вы нажимаете второй раз на `enter`, то `bookData` (если вы слишком быстро конечно не нажимали, а подождали немного) равна ответу полученному при первом нажатии на `enter`.

Вам не нужно использовать `bookData`, все что вам нужно, это вызвать `dispatch` сразу после того как был получен результат от сервера, то есть в `then` (где у вас сейчас вызывается `setData`) и передать в него уже `ArrayOfItemsFound(response.data)`